# How check old data in vue component after rendering?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, rendering, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to create a simple marketcap checker for crytpo (like coinmarketcap) using coingecko api.

I can fetch the data and render it, no problem with that. And I fetch the data 2 times per minutes.

But now, I would like to check if the new price is higher or lower than the last price.

I do a v-for loop and I pass some data in my "tokenComponent" for rendering the data like this :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="container mx-auto">
      <div class="pt-6">
        <h1 class="text-2xl font-bold">Crypto Monkey Cap</h1>
        <div v-for="token in listTokens" :key="token.id">
          <div class="py-6">
            <token-component
              :name="token.name"
              :price="token.current_price"
              :mcap="token.market_cap"
            ></token-component>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TokenComponent from "./components/tokenComponent.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    TokenComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      listTokens: [],
      lastPrice: 0
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getTokens();

    setInterval(() => {
      this.getTokens()
    }, 30000);
  },
  methods: {
    getTokens() {
    fetch("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.listTokens = data;
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

and the tokenComponent :

```
<template>
  <div class="py-4 border-2 rounded-lg">
    <div class="flex justify-around">
      <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
      <h2>{{ price }} $</h2>
      <h2>{{ mcap }} $</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: { required: true },
    price: { required: true },
    mcap: { required: true }
  }
};
</script>
```

I just would like put a conditionnal class in price data if the last price is higher or lower than the new one...

(I'm new in Vuejs... ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store previous prices to calculate if the last price is higher or lower than the new one. Use [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for that.

Added small example using setInterval instead of fetching new prices to display indicators

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    prices: [1]
  }),
  methods: {
    stonks(index) {
            if (index > 0) {
        return (this.prices[index] - this.prices[index-1]) > 0
            ? 'green' : 'red'
      }
    }
  },
  
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.prices.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1)
    }, 2000)
  }
})
```

```css
.prices {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}

.price {
  border:1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.stonks {
  position: absolute;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top:-8px;
  margin-right:-8px
}

.stonks.red { background: red; }
.stonks.green { background: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="prices">
    <div 
      v-for="(price, index) in prices" 
      :key="index" 
      class="price"
     >
      {{ price }}
      <div class="stonks" :class="stonks(index)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes thanks I understand but as you can see, I show the price (and other data) in an other component, not in the same. So, each time I fetch the data, I pass it to the new component (with proprs)  and show them. I don't have the old data in the component I render each time.

Comment: I have to check the price before sending data to new component and adding a new true/false variable maybe ?

Comment: Thats an option of course. I would suggest to add every new price to array to use them later. It will also allow you to build charts later for example. 
And then you can define new prop called `prevPrice` for `tokenComponent` component and make comparison there.

Comment: Ok thanks I see... But For the moment, I don't have database for register all that. I'm begining just with the new props ! Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need a database for this, you can store it in runtime (data) https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function